# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find Recipe with id=index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes, parameters

I am working on a Rails application, but came across the following error message.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RecipesController#show

Couldn't find recipe with id=index

Extracted source (around line #8)

def show
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]) # This line is highlighted in pink
end
```

I believe this has to do with my routes. The url to my index page is localhost:3000/games/index (I'm calling the index action on my recipes controller. I created that action through resources :recipe creating seven restful routes including index.) However, when I access it, ROR thinks I'm accessing a game with id of index, through the show route. The truth is I would like to set my index page to localhost:3000/recipes. I don't want the index at the end.

Here is my RecipesController

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @recipe = Recipe.all
  end

  def show
    @recipe = recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:id])
    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to @recipe
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

As you can see, I defined the 7 common RESTful routes and have finished 4 of them.

Here is my routes.rb file

```
Recipes::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :recipes
end
```

By declaring resources :recipes, I created 7 routes without having to declare them on multiple lines.

Here is the result of rake routes

```
Prefix     Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
recipes      GET    /recipes(.:format)          recipes#index
           POST   /recipes(.:format)          recipes#create
new_recipe   GET    /recipes/new(.:format)      recipes#new
edit_recipe  GET    /recipes/:id/edit(.:format) recipes#edit
recipe      GET    /recipes/:id(.:format)      recipes#show
           PATCH  /recipes/:id(.:format)      recipes#update
           PUT    /recipes/:id(.:format)      recipes#update
           DELETE /recipes/:id(.:format)      recipes#destroy
```

Here is my index.html.erb file located in apps/views/recipes directory

```
<h1>Here is a list of recipes</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Recipe</th>
    <th>Cook Time</th>
    <th>Prep Time</th>
    <th>Difficulty</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody> 
  <% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= recipe.recipe %></td>
      <td><%= recipe.cooktime %></td>
      <td><%= recipe.preptime %></td>
      <td><%= recipe.difficulty %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is my migrations file

```
class CreateRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :recipes do |t|
      t.string :recipe
      t.string :cooktime
      t.string :preptime
      t.integer :difficulty

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my application.html.erb file used as a template for every webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Recipes</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield %>

    <%= link_to "Home", recipes_path %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_recipe_path(:id) %>
    <%= link_to "New", new_recupe_path %>
    <%= link_to "Delete" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried creating ActiveRecord objects through rails console and had them saved. So ActiveRecord objects do exist with IDs. I don't know where I went wrong here.

If you need any more information, please let me know.

I appreciate any help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No idea.  But try posting the results of "rake routes" to help see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated the OP with all of my routes. All of them were declared from resources:games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what gives you this error? I could imagine calling `/games/index` would. Basically index is parsed as a parameter to the `/games/:id` route.

EDIT:

this is because of the `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_game_path(:id) %>` call in the layout template. Which is misplaced. You cannot edit if you are viewing `/games` because no `:id` is present.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is now, but I'm still not sure how to solve it. It's directed to localhost:3000/games/index but I want it to direct to localhost:3000/games. It thinks I'm trying to find a particular game with id-index but I'm trying to create an index page. I don't know what I did wrong because I created my routes through resources. Do I need to use root?

Comment: root is what you see if you visit `/` so no, it is not required and definitely not what gives you the `/games/index` route. When does 'it' directs to `localhost:3000/games/index`?

Comment: I understand now. It's because in my GamesController I called @game when it should have been at games. It was a small mistake but it caused me a lot of trouble. I'd like to thank you for your help.